# How to find the solution of $y'cosecx+y=1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know it is alittle elementary question. after multiplying $e^{-cosx}$ both sides.

$ye^{-cosx}=\int sinxe^{-cosx}dx$

I found the solution $y=1+ce^{cosx}$ from linear eq.

but when I try :

$\frac{dy}{1-y}=sinxdx$

$ln(1-y)=cosx-c$

$1-y=e^{cosx}-e^c$

$y=1-e^{cosx}-e^c$

$y=c_1-e^{cosx}$

I wonder why this results are different?

Comment: Third line after "but when I try" should be $1-y=e^{-c}e^{\cos x}$.  For $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$.

Comment: Is constant $1$ a solution?  (yes)  Does constant $1$ fit your formula $c_1-e^{\cos x}$? (no).  So a way to find your mistake  to look at all your steps and find the first one where the constant $1$ no longer works.

Comment: thanks. yes it should be $ln(1-y)+lnc=cosx$

Comment: There are also various complications, such as it really should be more like $\ln(|1-y|)$. Also, funny things happen with the constant of integration, sometimes in these manipulations we have to replace $e^{-c}$ by the more general $C$, which can be $0$, while $e^{-c}$ cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Is your equation $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}y'+y=1$?

When you write $ln(1-y)=cosx-c$ and $1-y=e^{cosx}-e^c$, you are doing it wrong. It should be
$ln|1-y|=cosx-c$ and $1-y=e^{cosx}\cdot e^c$

Solution: Rewrite $y'=(1-y)\sin(x)$ or $$\frac{dy}{1-y}=sin(x)dx$$

Now we integrate to get

$$-\ln{|1-y|}=-\ln(c)-\cos(x)$$
$$\ln{|1-y|}=\ln(c)+\cos(x)$$
$$|1-y|=ce^{\cos(x)}$$

Now you need to look at diffrent cases for the absolute value of $|1-y|$. Or simply write $\pm(1-y)$ instead.
$$\pm(1-y)=ce^{\cos(x)}$$
$$1-y=\mp ce^{\cos(x)}$$
$$y=1\pm ce^{\cos(x)}$$

As $c$ can be thought as a arbitrary constant. We can absorb the $\pm$ into a new constant $d$.

$$y=1+ de^{\cos(x)}$$